# Looping through multiple tabs of multiple google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working to create a "master" google sheet based on a folder of google sheet documents (currently 6 files). Each of these sheets have a slightly different number of tabs (some with slight name variations), but I want to loop a formula to get the values off of each tab within each sheet file. (ex. fileA has 3 tabs, I want to grab the data off of each tab and repeat similarly in fileB that has 4 tabs). I also want to skip a few named tabs.

Here is a piece of my code (2 interlaced functions):

```
function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID)
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

    for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    var data = []
      if(
       (sheet.getName() == "Summary") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "Data") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") ||
       (sheet.getName()== "Sheet2")
      ) continue;
      var lastrownum = sheet.getLastRow();
      var values = sheet.getRange("A2:L" + lastrownum).getValues();
      data = data.concat(values)
      Logger.log(data);
      return data;
     }
}
```

However, this is only grabbing/saving data from one tab in each file that is not named "Summary", "Data", etc.

How do I get it to loop through all the (non-excluded) tabs in all sheet files??? I am unable to edit the files as this is to create an automated system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

It is not a good practice to use `for...in` to iterate over arrays in javascript. If you want to learn more please refer to this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

However there are two issues in your code:

1. You have `var data = []` **inside** the loop and every time you redefine the array and therefore previous values are cleared.
2. You use the `return` statement **inside** the loop which means the function will be terminated in the first iteration, since the return is the stopping point of the execution of every function.

### Solution (recommended):

I would advice you to use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID){

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID)
  const allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  const sheetsToExclude = ["Summary","Data","Sheet1","Sheet2"];
  const data = [];
  allsheets.forEach(sheet=>{ 
    if(!sheetsToExclude.includes(sheet.getName())){
      var lastrownum = sheet.getLastRow();
      var values = sheet.getRange("A2:L" + lastrownum).getValues();
      data = data.concat(values) 
    }
});
   Logger.log(data);
   return data;
}
```

### But your solution (after fixing the issues) would work like this:

```
function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID)
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  var data = []
    for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];        
      if(
       (sheet.getName() == "Summary") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "Data") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") ||
       (sheet.getName()== "Sheet2")
      ) continue;
      var lastrownum = sheet.getLastRow();
      var values = sheet.getRange("A2:L" + lastrownum).getValues();
      data = data.concat(values)          
     }
  Logger.log(data);
  return data;
}
```